# Iteratively renaming objects in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to iteratively rename objects in python? I'm trying to code something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(5000):
phat_i = i/5000
print(i/5000)
```

It doesn't seem like this will work because even if this created a new objected named "phat_i," it seems like it would just redefine that object for each "i." Instead, I want to create new objects "phat_1," "phat_2," etc. for each "i."

I've already looked at this question but the only answer to it seems to have not answered my question.
[Maya Python: Renaming object with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370596/maya-python-renaming-object-with-for-loops)

Comment: Generally a bad idea to dynamically create variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Create Variables in For Loop, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191730/dynamically-create-variables-in-for-loop-python)

Comment: There are dozens of posts like this ^^^ and most of them usually say the same thing: *don't create variables dynamically*. There are zero good reasons to do so, and there are likely a few dozen ways to achieve what you need with something safer.

Answer (score 2):

`eval()` and `exec()` could be used but they're bad practices since they can be exploited.

Instead, I suggest using dictionaries.

```py
phat_ = {}
for i in range(5000):
    phat_[i] = i/5000
```